# A java App which runs in intelliJ But not runs in cmd

Tags: java, mysql

I develop a java application which perfectly runs on intelliJ but when i want to run it in terminal using `java` command, it throws an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at Server.main(Server.java:9)
```

Here is my main Code that cause exception in first line after try clause:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            DBClass.createDB();
            DBClass.purgeHubs();
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9898);
            System.out.println("Server Running!");
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                socket.setSoTimeout(20*1000); // The Connected Socket Must Send Anything Within 20 Seconds Otherwise it will be closed.
                Thread t = new Thread(() -> ClientManager.getInstance().run(socket));
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

btw I also added mysql jar file in project:
[image]

Comment: can you show the java command you ran?

Comment: Having the mysql jar in the project means it's available when working within Intellij. However, when you run it in command line, you need to put it, and all the other external jars, in the classpath.

Comment: @Bosco first I compile it with `javac` command and then run it using `java` command normally.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks. I tried this command: `java Server -cp [mysql.jar absolute path]` but no luck. how i can put external libs in the classpath?

Comment: The classpath has to include all your jars, separated by colon (in Linux) or semicolon (in Windows). Please read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your java class file with the following command :

java -cp Path:path/to/mysql.jar package1.package2.Server

First Path refers to the Server.class absolute address.